# Simplest way to return an array of group matches?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex:

```
<[a-z]+>(.{2,}?)<\/
```

To extract from this string

```
<OperatingSystem>Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434)</OperatingSystem> <Processor>Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.5GHz</Processor>  <Memory>16384MB RAM</Memory>    <UserDPISettings>96 DPI (100 percent)</UserDPISettings> <CardName>NVIDIA Quadro K2000</CardName>    <DedicatedMemory>2007 MB</DedicatedMemory>  <CurrentMode>1920 x 1200 (32 bit) (59Hz)</CurrentMode>  <NativeMode>1920 x 1200(p) (59.950Hz)</NativeMode>  <DriverVersion>26.21.14.4166</DriverVersion>    <DriverVersion>6.00.0001.6070</DriverVersion>
```

an array of selected groups (not the full matches, see [the difference](https://regex101.com/r/c6XJZo/1/)):

```
[[Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434), Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.5GHz, 16384MB RAM, 96 DPI (100 percent), NVIDIA Quadro K2000, 2007 MB, 1920 x 1200 (32 bit) (59Hz), 1920 x 1200(p) (59.950Hz), 26.21.14.4166, 6.00.0001.6070]]
```

Is the following code the simplest way to do that?

```
  let r = /<[a-z]+>(.{2,}?)<\//gi, out = []; //Extract everything between quotes
  let arr = [...str.matchAll(r)]; 
  out = arr.map(x => x[1]);
```

If I run the following, I get an array of full matches:

```
var out = str.match(r); //["<OperatingSystem>Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 17763) (17763.rs5_release.180914-1434)</", "<Processor>Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.5GHz</", "<Memory>16384MB RAM</", "<UserDPISettings>96 DPI (100 percent)</", "<CardName>NVIDIA Quadro K2000</", "<DedicatedMemory>2007 MB</", "<CurrentMode>1920 x 1200 (32 bit) (59Hz)</", "<NativeMode>1920 x 1200(p) (59.950Hz)</", "<DriverVersion>26.21.14.4166</", "<DriverVersion>6.00.0001.6070</"]
```

Is there something similar to str.match(r) for returning an array of the groups directly?

Thanks!

**Edit:** The simplest way I've found is:

```
let r = /<[a-z]+>(.{2,}?)<\//gi, out = []; 
let arr= Array.from(str.matchAll(r), m => m[1]);
```

An even easier solution is to use lookbehinds and lookaheads to just select the fields you are interested in, as demonstrated in [this example](https://regex101.com/r/SOtKKz/1) with the following regex:

```
/(?<=>\b).*?(?=<\/)/gi
```

That way you skip all the extra steps to extract the group matches and just get an array of the results you want with a mere str.match(r).

Comment: `arr2.map(x => out.push(x[1]));` this looks like blatant misuse of `map`. Also, what's `arr2`?

Comment: arr2 was meant to be just arr (fixed it). I'm using map to get the second column of the arr (each row has [full match, group match])

Comment: So basically `out = [...str.matchAll(r)].map(x => x[1])` i guess, and i don't think it will get much nicer.